# Alternate way for swapping two numbers

Tags: python, struct

Is there a more elegant way to perform the below task, say by using a *struct* (as in C) rather than have a list of 2 numbers:

```
def swapnumbers(alist):
    temp = alist[0]
    alist[0] = alist[1]
    alist[1] = temp

alist = [1, 2]
```

Comment: in python `a,b = b,a` is a great statement

Comment: @Jiten , are you doing a backtracking algorithm by any chance?

Comment: AFAIK , The last line should be `alist[1] = temp`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can do `alist.reverse()`. The [`reverse`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) method of `list`s reverses the elements in place (and works for lists of any (positive) length).

Comment: Not quite sure reversing is the same as swapping elements

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a temp variable, just swap the elements :

```
def swapnumbers(alist):
    alist[0], alist[1] = alist[1], alist[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
a = [1, 2]
a[0] = a[0] + a[1]
a[1] = a[0] - a[1]
a[0] = a[0] - a[1]
```

Comment: I would like to retract my delete vote ... this will work if you change the comma's to semicolons

Comment: that should also be removed :P

Comment: @BhargavRao: Jimmy wrote this as a *sentence* containing instructions (hence the commas and the period), not as copy/pasteable code.  That's not how we do things around here, but it's not crazy.  This code doesn't work for things you can't add; it doesn't work for cases where you'd lose precision in the arithmetic; but it's kind of cute, nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Well sure there is

```
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> a[0],a[1] = a[1],a[0]
>>> a
[2, 1]
```